# All prime ideals in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We know that all maximal ideals of  $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ are of the form $(X-a,Y-b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. All height one prime ideals are principal. Similarly all maximal ideals of  $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$ are of the form $(X-a,Y-b,Z-c)$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$. Can we say some special properties about height one and two prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$ like prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$?

Comment: Height one prime ideals are principal in this ring because it's a UFD. But beyond that, I don't really think there's much in the way of useful things to say here - you're asking for a complete classification of all subvarieties of $\Bbb A^3_{\Bbb C}$, and there's a lot of them. For instance, any smooth affine curve over $\Bbb C$ embeds here.